# Xamarin Forms Custom Map Pin

Tags: xamarin.forms, maps, customization

In one of the apps I'm working on I require the use of custom map pins and I've followed the guide on Xamarin https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/ as well as borrowed their sample code to try and make my own example.

It works to a degree in such that the info window is actually updated to the custom layout but the map pin never changes.

[image: [Imgur]

My CustomMapRenderer:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Android.Widget;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;
using WorkingWithMaps.Droid.Renderers;
using WorkingWithMaps;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace WorkingWithMaps.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        GoogleMap map;
        List<CustomPin> customPins;
        bool isDrawn;



        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                map.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
                ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        void IOnMapReadyCallback.OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {

            map = googleMap;
            map.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
            map.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
            this.NativeMap = googleMap;
        }


        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName.Equals("VisibleRegion") && !isDrawn)
            {
                map.Clear();

                foreach (var pin in customPins)
                {
                    var marker = new MarkerOptions();
                    marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Pin.Position.Longitude));
                    marker.SetTitle(pin.Pin.Label);
                    marker.SetSnippet(pin.Pin.Address);
                    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));

                    map.AddMarker(marker);
                }
                isDrawn = true;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

            if (changed)
            {
                isDrawn = false;
            }
        }

        void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Url))
            {
                var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, url);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
        {
            var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
            if (inflater != null)
            {
                Android.Views.View view;

                var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
                if (customPin == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
                }

                if (customPin.Id == "Xamarin")
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow, null);
                }
                else
                {
                    view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);
                }

                var infoTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowTitle);
                var infoSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle);

                if (infoTitle != null)
                {
                    infoTitle.Text = marker.Title;
                }
                if (infoSubtitle != null)
                {
                    infoSubtitle.Text = marker.Snippet;
                }

                return view;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
        {
            return null;
        }

        CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
        {
            var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);
            foreach (var pin in customPins)
            {
                if (pin.Pin.Position == position)
                {
                    return pin;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and my map page, also heavily borrowed from Xamarin's working with maps guide

```
using Plugin.Geolocator;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace WorkingWithMaps
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        CustomMap map;
        Geocoder geoCoder;
        String navAdd;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var maplocator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            maplocator.DesiredAccuracy = 1;
            geoCoder = new Geocoder();

            map = new CustomMap
            {
                HeightRequest = 100,
                WidthRequest = 960,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                IsShowingUser = true
            };

            map.MapType = MapType.Street;
            map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(55.237208, 10.479160), Distance.FromMeters(500)));
            map.IsShowingUser = true;

            var street = new Button { Text = "Street" };
            var hybrid = new Button { Text = "Hybrid" };
            var satellite = new Button { Text = "Satellite" };
            street.Clicked += HandleClickedAsync;
            hybrid.Clicked += HandleClickedAsync;
            //satellite.Clicked += OnReverseGeocodeButtonClicked;
            var segments = new StackLayout
            {
                Spacing = 30,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Children = { street, hybrid, satellite }
            };

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                Children = { map, segments }
            };

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {
                try
                {

                    //var currentpos = await maplocator.GetPositionAsync(1000);
                    //map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(currentpos.Latitude, currentpos.Longitude), Distance.FromMeters(500)));

                    if (!maplocator.IsListening)
                    {
                        await maplocator.StartListeningAsync(1000, 50, true);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Fail" + ex);
                }
            });

            var pin = new CustomPin
            {
                Pin = new Pin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(55.240121, 10.469895),
                    Label = "Testing Pins"
                }
            };

            map.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };
            map.Pins.Add(pin.Pin);

            map.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.PropertyName + " just changed!");
                if (e.PropertyName == "VisibleRegion" && map.VisibleRegion != null)
                    CalculateBoundingCoordinates(map.VisibleRegion);
            };

            maplocator.PositionChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var position = e.Position;

                map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude), Distance.FromKilometers(2)));
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        //async void OnReverseGeocodeButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    var possibleAddresses = await geoCoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(pin.Position);
        //    navAdd += possibleAddresses.ElementAt(0) + "\n";

        //    switch (Device.OS)
        //    {
        //        case TargetPlatform.iOS:
        //            Device.OpenUri(new Uri(string.Format("http://maps.apple.com/?q={0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(navAdd))));
        //            break;
        //        case TargetPlatform.Android:
        //            Device.OpenUri(new Uri(string.Format("geo:0,0?q={0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode(navAdd))));
        //            break;
        //        case TargetPlatform.Windows:
        //        case TargetPlatform.WinPhone:
        //            Device.OpenUri(new Uri(string.Format("bingmaps:?where={0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(navAdd))));
        //            break;
        //    }
        //}


        void HandleClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var b = sender as Button;
            switch (b.Text)
            {
                case "Street":
                    map.MapType = MapType.Street;
                    break;
                case "Hybrid":
                    map.MapType = MapType.Hybrid;
                    break;
                case "Satellite":
                    map.MapType = MapType.Satellite;
                    break;
            }
        }

        static void CalculateBoundingCoordinates(MapSpan region)
        {
            var center = region.Center;
            var halfheightDegrees = region.LatitudeDegrees / 2;
            var halfwidthDegrees = region.LongitudeDegrees / 2;

            var left = center.Longitude - halfwidthDegrees;
            var right = center.Longitude + halfwidthDegrees;
            var top = center.Latitude + halfheightDegrees;
            var bottom = center.Latitude - halfheightDegrees;

            if (left < -180) left = 180 + (180 + left);
            if (right > 180) right = (right - 180) - 180;

            Debug.WriteLine("Bounding box:");
            Debug.WriteLine("                    " + top);
            Debug.WriteLine("  " + left + "                " + right);
            Debug.WriteLine("                    " + bottom);
        }

    }
}
```

On top of the mentioned issue the implementation has also caused `IsShowingUser = True` to no longer function as well as

```
var currentpos = await maplocator.GetPositionAsync(1000);
```

to throw an exception.

Github repository: https://github.com/Mortp/CustomMapPinsXamarin

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. My pin is working. Also how this compiles:"this.NativeMap = googleMap;" NativeMap is a readonly property. If you can share your sample project I might be able to find the problem

Comment: @YuriS I've added a link to my project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I would like to provide 2 links that helped me to understand the problem. Thank you guys.
[Xamarin.Forms.Maps 2.3.4 custom MapRenderer disables everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43374960/xamarin-forms-maps-2-3-4-custom-maprenderer-disables-everything) and https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92565/android-ionmapreadycallback-forms-2-3-4

Latest Xamarin Maps broke OnElementPropertyChanged with VisibleRegion. They defined that MapRenderer now implements IOnMapReadyCallback and that broke somehow OnElementPropertyChanged (I didn't investigate how and why). As you can see in link I provided there are 2 methods you can go. To keep your renderer implementing IOnMapReadyCallback or not. When I kept IOnMapReadyCallback I started to get 2 pins - one of top another - our custom pin and regular pin. I didn't dig more how that happens and removed IOnMapReadyCallback. After that things became really simple because if you let Xamarin handle it and create NativeMap you can remove some code and make renderer simpler.

Before I post the code I also want to mention that when I fixed it the app started crashing with OutOfMemory exception and I found out that your pin image is 2000 pixels width. I changed it to 40. Below is the code:

```
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter//, IOnMapReadyCallback
{
    bool isDrawn;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
        }

    }


    bool isMapReady;
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (!isMapReady && (NativeMap != null))
        {
            NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);
            NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
            isMapReady = true;
        }

        if (e.PropertyName.Equals("VisibleRegion") && !isDrawn)
        {
            NativeMap.Clear();

            foreach (var pin in ((CustomMap)Element).CustomPins)
            {
                var marker = new MarkerOptions();
                marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Pin.Position.Longitude));
                marker.SetTitle(pin.Pin.Label);
                marker.SetSnippet(pin.Pin.Address);
                marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));

                NativeMap.AddMarker(marker);
            }
            isDrawn = true;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

        if (changed)
        {
            isDrawn = false;
        }
    }

    void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Url))
        {
            var url = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, url);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
        var inflater = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as Android.Views.LayoutInflater;
        if (inflater != null)
        {
            Android.Views.View view;

            var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            if (customPin.Id == "Xamarin")
            {
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.XamarinMapInfoWindow, null);
            }
            else
            {
                view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.MapInfoWindow, null);
            }

            var infoTitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowTitle);
            var infoSubtitle = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.InfoWindowSubtitle);

            if (infoTitle != null)
            {
                infoTitle.Text = marker.Title;
            }
            if (infoSubtitle != null)
            {
                infoSubtitle.Text = marker.Snippet;
            }

            return view;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public Android.Views.View GetInfoWindow(Marker marker)
    {
        return null;
    }

    CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
    {
        var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);
        foreach (var pin in ((CustomMap)Element).CustomPins)
        {
            if (pin.Pin.Position == position)
            {
                return pin;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


}
```

[image]