# Xamarin Forms changeing MapType with custom renderer isn't working

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I took this [sample project](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/customrenderers/map/pin/) and added buttons in the xaml code

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomRenderer;assembly=CustomRenderer"
         x:Class="CustomRenderer.MapPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" 
                     Spacing="10"
                     Padding="10"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Button x:Name="ButtonStreet" Text="Street" Clicked="OnStreetClicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="ButtonHybrid" Text="Hybrid" Clicked="OnHybridClicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="ButtonSatellite" Text="Satellite" Clicked="OnSatelliteClicked"/>
            <Button x:Name="ButtonAddPin" Text="Add Pin" Clicked="OnAddPinClicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <local:CustomMap x:Name="customMap" MapType="Street" WidthRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenWidth}" HeightRequest="{x:Static local:App.ScreenHeight}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

And added the clicked event to the code behind

```
        private void OnStreetClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customMap.MapType = MapType.Street;
    }

    private void OnHybridClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customMap.MapType = MapType.Hybrid;
    }

    private void OnSatelliteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customMap.MapType = MapType.Satellite;
    }
```

I noticed that the reason that it doesn't change is because of the OnMapReady method in the CustomMapRenderer class. Changeing to a Forms map solves the problem with updateing the MapType. But will probably give me other problems. What should I do?

```
public void OnMapReady (GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        map = googleMap;
        map.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
        map.SetInfoWindowAdapter (this);
    }
```

Comment: check what to do with OnMapReady here and vote if it solves your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44669945/xamarin-forms-custom-map-pin/44767711#44767711

Comment: Thanks, that helped me! I removed IOnMapReadyCallback